# Best data structure for a sparse ordered 2D array of floats allowing interpolation (perl)

Tags: perl, data-structures

The data are stock options. I want to make a 2D array based on days till expiration (int) & normalized distance out of the money (float), with the values being a list of normalized bid and ask prices. If the desired element is not in the array, I want to be able to interpolate between the nearest elements present.

I see 3 possible data structures:

1. A sparse 2D array, maybe 10000 elements, maybe 1/3 full.
2. A 2D linked list, ie: 4 listpointers for each data element (so 3000 elements becomes 15000)
3. A 2D hash (maybe 3000 elements), with 2 sorted lists of the keys (maybe 100 elements each) in each dimension.

The main problem is efficient retrieval when interpolation is required.
Retrieval of existing elements is relatively straight-forward with any method.

I'm currently using choice 3, but retrieval is a bit of a kloodge, since I have to scan along the keylists of each dimension till I find occupied elements, and then do a 2- or 4-way interpolation.
I use moreUtils::firstindx($_ > $desiredKey) to find the keys. The linked lists (choice 2) would spare me the search of the keylist arrays.

Choice 1 would also require scanning, wouldn't need the initial step of keylist lookup, but might need to look at more empty cells. And insertion would be a real hassle.

I would be doing many more searches than insertions.

Does any one have any suggestions for the most efficient data structure.

Comment: Do you need to insert into the list, be it the interpolated results or other elements? If not, a sorted array + binsearch sounds great. It's easy to write a binsearch such that it returns the index where the element would be found if it's not found (as shown [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=383504#binsearch)). This requires at most log(N) comparisons (~12 for 3000 elements) rather than your existing approach that could take up to N comparisons (3000 your 3000 elements). Insertions requires memcpy-ing less than N/2 pointers in C, so still quite fast.

Comment: Also consider using a database (e.g. sqlite). It should get you close to max efficiency with minimal effort.

Comment: Thanks ikegami - I'm not sure how I'd sort a 2D array. As for the keylist arrays I use now, they're short enough (<300 items) that I can just resort after inserting. I don't know how firstindx searches, but it does give me the indices of the bracketing existing elements for each dimension. Also, I'd like to do this in memory, and doesn't sqlite keep the data on disc? I'd be running this in real time and there might be ~10000 lookups.

Comment: Re "*I'm not sure how I'd sort a 2D array.*", By what you search. If you can interpolate the results between two points, there must be an order to the points, right? What do lookup by? /// If you follow the link I posted, it also shows how to insert into a sorted array. It's O(N), so it scales slight better than append+re-sort (O(N log N)), and also much faster. /// firstidx necessarily searches linearly. In fact, simply calling the sub is O(N) because it places N+1 arguments on the stack. /// You can create an in-memory table. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`, IIRC

Comment: Re " What do lookup by? " The main data is in a hash of hashes. I look up the keys of each hash in their respective sorted arrays, and insert them into the hash. Items which are close in one dimension may be very distant in another. I don't see how a binary search would work on that. Currently, for a non-existent item, I have to scan up and down each of the keylists to find 4 the bracketing values.

Comment: So use two sorted arrays. (The values are indexes into the unsorted data array.) But I don't see how you can interpolate with that kind of data, assuming you could have two values with the same lifespan and/or same distance. Can you have two values with the same lifespan? Can you have two values with the same distance?

Comment: For each lifespan I can have elements with any distance, and vice versa. At least for now, I can't have elements that have both keys the same. The 2 sorted arrays are the sorted keys of the 2 levels of hashes. The way I interpolate if neither time or distance match is to find the 4 closest defined elements, which now takes a lot of scanning. That's why I'm looking for a possible other data structure. The 2-way linked list would let me get to the nearest defined elements in one step, but would take 4x the space.

Comment: Re "*find the 4 closest defined elements*", So you need to lookup by closeness. How do you define closeness?

Comment: The 2 dimensions are essentially incommensurable, so I interpolate on the distances for the next higher and lower times (opposite sides of the boxes), then interpolate those values between the times (the other 2 sides).

Comment: So it's not 4 closest elements, but 2 closest lifetimes, and 2 closest distances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you predominantly perform lookups by lifespan and lookups by distance, and few inserts, I'd use sorted arrays to lookup the records by binary search.

- Locating an existing element: O(log N)
- Locating the box of a missing element: O(log N)
- Inserting: O(N)

Given,

```
my @data = (
   [ $lifespan0, $distance0, $bid0, $ask0 ],
   [ $lifespan1, $distance1, $bid1, $ask1 ],
   ...
);

my $lifespan_search_cmp = sub { $a <=> $data[$b][0] };
my $distance_search_cmp = sub { $a <=> $data[$b][1] };
```

First, create indexes:

```
my @by_lifespan = sort { $data[$a][0] <=> $data[$b][0] } 0..$#data;
my @by_distance = sort { $data[$a][1] <=> $data[$b][1] } 0..$#data;
```

To lookup:

```
my $i = binsearch_first \&$lifespan_search_cmp, $lifespan, @by_lifespan;
my $j = binsearch_first \&$distance_search_cmp, $distance, @by_distance;

my @lifespan_matching_idxs = get_run_forward \&$lifespan_search_cmp, $lifespan, $i, @by_lifespan;
my @distance_matching_idxs = get_run_forward \&$distance_search_cmp, $distance, $j, @by_distance;

my @cross_match_idxs = do {
   my %lifespan_matching_idxs = map { $_ => 1 } @lifespan_matching_idxs;
   grep { $lifespan_matching_idxs{$_} }
      @distance_matching_idxs
};

if (@cross_match_idxs) {
   # Exact match(es) found.
   ...
} else {
   my $lifespan_lowerbracket;
   my $lifespan_upperbracket;
   if ($i >= 0) {
      $lifespan_lowerbracket = $lifespan;
      $lifespan_upperbracket = $lifespan;
   } else {
      die "Can't interpolate" if ~$i == 0 || ~$i >= @by_lifespan;
      $lifespan_lowerbracket = $data[~$i    ][0];
      $lifespan_lowerbracket = $data[~$i - 1][0];
   }

   my $distance_lowerbracket;
   my $distance_upperbracket;
   if ($i >= 0) {
      $distance_lowerbracket = $distance;
      $distance_upperbracket = $distance;
   } else {
      die "Can't interpolate" if ~$j == 0 || ~$j >= @by_distance;
      $distance_lowerbracket = $data[~$j    ][1];
      $distance_upperbracket = $data[~$j - 1][1];
   }

   ...
}
```

To insert:

```
my $i = binsearch_first \&$lifespan_search_cmp, $lifespan, @by_lifespan;
my $j = binsearch_first \&$distance_search_cmp, $distance, @by_distance;

push @data, [ $lifespan, $distance , $bid, $ask ];

splice(@by_lifespan, $i >= 0 ? $i : ~$i, 0, $#data);
splice(@by_distance, $j >= 0 ? $j : ~$j, 0, $#data);
```

Subs:

```
sub binsearch_first(&$\@) {
   my  $compare = $_[0];
   #my $value   = $_[1];
   my  $array   = $_[2];

   my $min = 0;
   my $max = $#$array;
   return -1 if $max == -1;

   my $ap = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{caller().'::a'} };  local *$ap;
   my $bp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{caller().'::b'} };  local *$bp;

   *$ap = \($_[1]);
   while ($min <= $max) {
      my $mid = int(($min+$max)/2);
      *$bp = \($array->[$mid]);

      my $cmp = $compare->();
      if ($cmp < 0) {
         $max = $mid - 1;
      }
      elsif ($cmp > 0) {
         $min = $mid + 1;
      }
      else {
         return $mid if $mid == $min;
         $max = $mid;
      }
   }

   # Converts unsigned int to signed int.
   return unpack('j', pack('J', ~$min));
}

sub get_run_forward(&$\@) {
   my  $compare = $_[0];
   #my $value   = $_[1];
   my  $start   = $_[2];
   my  $array   = $_[3];

   return if $start < 0;

   my $ap = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{caller().'::a'} };  local *$ap;
   my $bp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{caller().'::b'} };  local *$bp;

   *$ap = \($_[1]);

   my $i = $start;
   while ($i <= $#$array) {
      *$bp = \($array->[$i]);

      my $cmp = $compare->()
         and last;

      ++$i;
   }

   return wantarray ? ($start..$i-1) : $i-1;
}
```

You might want to use a tolerance in the floating-point comparions (i.e. in `$distance_search_cmp`).

Comment: Thanks ikegami! You've really spent some time on this! Your solution looks sort of like what I was doing, except my code is a kloodge, and yours is elegant. :-) I'll give it a try,

Comment: You're welcome. Look at CPAN for a c-based binsearch to speed things up.  Make sure it always finds the first result if there are more than one

Comment: You could eliminate the need for `get_run_forward` by using a third lookup array sorted by lifespan then by distance. The value of the elements could be an array of indexes to handle elements with the same lifespan and distance.